# Hosting website for local users

Tags: mysql, web, hosting, lan

i have a website that i use it on "LAN"  how many users can access this website with MySql database hosted on phpmyadmin ( xampp ) what is the minimum resources for the server i need. is windows 7 for the server OK for hosting the website or windows server will be better and tell me why please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my answers based on your minimum informations.

How many user can access? = depends on your apps and your server resources. Knowing that it's only on LAN then bandwidth will not be a big issue.

Minimum resources = depends on much resources your apps need and how many client that you will serve, concurrent or not.

Server version is always better to be a server (windows server, ubuntu server, etc)because they provide better resources management and better security.

Comment: Thanks yogi for your answer now am using the Ubuntu server, but do you have any idea on how to manage the server resources to full using ?